# UITableViewCell 1行の中に複数配置されたUIButtonのタップイベントを、上位クラス(ViewContoller)で受ける方法

Tags: swift, tableview

テーブルビューの使い方について聞きたいのですが、

下記ソースを想定した、1行のセル内に複数のボタンを配置させたとき、
どのボタンが配置されたかのイベントを上位のクラス(ViewControllerなど)で判別することは可能でしょうか？
方法が分からず、行き詰ってます。ご教授ください。

**VIewController.swift**

```
class ViewController:UITableViewController{
　・・・
　// セルの内容を設定するメソッド
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      if(indexPath.row == 0){
        // 【注目】
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "testcell", for: indexPath) as! myCusutomCell
        return cell
　　　　・・・・
     }
     ・・・・
   }

   // myCusutomCellの中にある複数のボタンのタップ情報をここで（ViewController内で）受けたい

}

// testcell
class myCusutomCell:UITableViewCell{

　button1 ~
  button2 ~
  button3 ~

}
```

Answer (score 1):

2種類の方法をご紹介します。まず、レスポンダーチェーンを使う方法です。

### Responder Chainによるイベントの受け渡し

レスポンダーチェーンは、Macのアプリケーションを開発した経験のある方なら、メニューバーのメニュー実装などでよく使われる手法なのですが、iOSのアプリ開発では、直接はあまりお目にかかりません。しかし、タッチイベント（`func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)`）の伝播など、影で活躍しているメカニズムなので、しっかり学習し、理解しなければいけません。
レスポンダーチェーンとは、そのまま直訳した「応答の鎖」がよく表現しているように、ユーザなどが起こしたイベントを、複数の鎖で繋がれた`UIResponder`のオブジェクトの間で、次々に受け渡していく機構です。鎖のどこかのオブジェクトに、イベントを処理するアクションメソッド（`@IBAction`）が実装されていると、そこでアクションメソッドが実行されます。
Storyboardの編集画面で、View Controllerに"First Responder"という項目があるのに、お気づきになりましたか？これがレスポンダーチェーンの先端を意味します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

First Responderのアイコンにボタンなどの`UIControl`オブジェクトから接続（Connect）をすると、特定のオブジェクトにではなく、レスポンダーチェーンに命令（Action）を送ることができます。
まず、First ResponderのAttributes Inspectorを表示し、新規アクションを登録します。下図では、`doSomething`というアクションを登録しています。「Type」は、今回は汎用性を考えて、`NSObject`としています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ボタンオブジェクトからFirst Responderに接続（Connect）を行うと、プルダウンメニューの中に、先ほど登録したアクション`doSomething`が見つかりますので、それを選択します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

これでStoryboardの編集は完了です。次に、`ViewController`クラスに、イベントを受け取るアクションメソッドを実装します。

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func doSomething(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Hello")
    }

    ........
}
```

以上の編集で、テーブルセル上のボタンをタップすると、「Hello」が出力されるようになります。
`UIViewController`のサブクラスは、オートマチックにレスポンダーチェーンの最後に近い方に位置付けられるので、ほぼどのようなイベントも受け取ることができます。

First Responderへの接続を、Storyboardでなく、プログラムで行う場合は、`UIControl`クラスのメソッド、[`Instance Method addTarget(_:action:for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618259-addtarget)を使います。このメソッドの引数`target`の型がオプショナル（Any?）であることに注目して、リファレンスの説明をご覧ください。

> target 
>   The target object—that is, the object whose action method is
>   called. If you specify nil, UIKit searches the responder chain for an
>   object that responds to the specified action message and delivers the
>   message to that object.

「If you specify nil,」の後「UIKitは、レスポンダーチェーンの中から、セレクタ（`action:`）に応答するオブジェクトを探し出し、そのオブジェクトにアクションを送り届けます」とあるところは、そのままレスポンダーチェーンを簡潔に説明した文になっています。

---

### Table ViewをStatic Cellsモードにする

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

`UITableViewController`のもとにあるTable Viewは、Static Cellsというモードにできます。その名のとおり、セルを動的に再利用するメカニズムを使わずに、セルを静的に配置するものですが、このモードでは、セル上に配置したボタン類のコントロール（`UIControl`）と、`UITableViewController`サブクラスに定義したアクションメソッド（`@IBAction`）を接続できるという利点があります。「ボタンがセル上にあるから……」という意識をせずに、Storyboard上の編集だけで完結するメリットは大きいでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます！アプリ起動の時点ではButtonの数が確定でなく、可変の場合でも同様に区別することは可能なのでしょうか？またコードでbuttonを定義する場合に同様の方針は可能でしょうか？