# UITableViewCell内の横長スクロールビュー内に配置されたボタン情報を受け取る方法

Tags: swift, uitableview

Tableviewcellにサブビューとしてスクロールビューを配置し、さらにそのスクロールビュー内にUIButtonを配置、ボタンのタップイベント（buttonEvent）を上位のクラスである
TopViewController内で処理をしたいと考えています。

下記のような構成で実装をしており、
createCotensView()のbutton.addTargetでタップイベント（buttonEvent）の処理先をTopVIewControllerに渡しているのですが、イベントがコールされません。

どこか誤った記述をしているのでしょうか？自力では解決できず困っております、
ご教授よろしくお願いします。

**TopVIewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
class TopViewController:UITableViewController{

    〜省略

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            〜〜省略

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "testcell", for: indexPath) as! tableCustomCell

        return cell
    }

    @objc func buttonEvent(_ sender: Any){
        print("ボタンが押されました")
        // ここの処理をtableCustomCellから呼び出したい！
    }

}


class tableCustomCell:UITableViewCell,UIScrollViewDelegate{

    // セル内に横長のスクロールビューを配置
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    ・・・省略

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // サブビューを作る
        let subView = createCotensView()

        // スクロールビューにサブビューを追加
        scrollView.addSubview(subView)

        // スクロールビューをサブビュー分の長さに拡張
        scrollView.contentSize = subView.frame.size
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x:0,y:0)

    }

    // スクロールビューに追加するコンテンツビュー(サブビュー)を追加
    func createCotensView() -> UIView{

        // コンテンツビューに複数のUIViewを配置
        let contentView = UIView()
        // 1ページの幅と高さ(幅はデバイスで変化するのでviewに合わせる)
        let pageWidth = 240
        let pageHeight = 214
        let pageViewRect = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:pageWidth,height:pageHeight)

        // 個別ビューを横方向に４つ、同じ間隔で配置
        for i in 0..<4{
            // 個別ビューを作る
            let pageView = UIView(frame: pageViewRect)

            // ボタンをビューの上に配置する
            let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        　　・・・buttonのデザインを定義(省略)

            // TopViewControllerのbuttonEventが呼ばれない！
            button.addTarget(TopViewController(), action: #selector(TopViewController.buttonEvent(_:)), for:UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)//

            pageView.addSubview(button)

            // 個別ビューの座標を決める(ページ幅だけずらしていく)
            let left = pageViewRect.width * CGFloat(i)
            let xy = CGPoint(x:left,y:0)
            pageView.frame = CGRect(origin: xy, size: pageViewRect.size)

            // createPage()で作成したViewを右方向へ配置していく
            contentView.addSubview(pageView)
        }



        return contentView
    }


}
```

Comment: あちこち省略されてしまっていて、回答にまとめられるようなコードが書けないので、コメントで。***処理先をTopVIewControllerに渡している*** 正しく渡せていません。処理先(`target`)に渡すべきは「実際に画面表示をしているインスタンス」です。`TopVIewController`のインスタンスなら何でも良い訳ではありません。あなたのコードでは、画面表示に全く関係ない`TopVIewController`のインスタンスを作り出して、`target`に渡しており、そのインスタンスはすぐに捨てられてしまいます。また`tableCustomCell`の(クラス名は大文字で始めましょう)`layoutSubviews()`の使い方が根本的に間違っています。`layoutSubviews()`はiOSがviewのレイアウト調整＝既に存在する子viewの位置や大きさの調整をする時に呼ぶメソッドです。その中でview階層を壊すような処理(子viewを使いすると言った)をしてはいけません。

Comment: 次の投稿はあなたの質問の回答になりますか？ [UITableViewCell 1行の中に複数配置されたUIButtonのタップイベントを、上位クラス(ViewContoller)で受ける方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/62297/uitableviewcell-1%e8%a1%8c%e3%81%ae%e4%b8%ad%e3%81%ab%e8%a4%87%e6%95%b0%e9%85%8d%e7%bd%ae%e3%81%95%e3%82%8c%e3%81%9fuibutton%e3%81%ae%e3%82%bf%e3%83%83%e3%83%97%e3%82%a4%e3%83%99%e3%83%b3%e3%83%88%e3%82%92-%e4%b8%8a%e4%bd%8d%e3%82%af%e3%83%a9%e3%82%b9viewcontoller%e3%81%a7%e5%8f%97%e3%81%91%e3%82%8b%e6%96%b9%e6%b3%95)

Comment: 知識が足らずすみませんが、「実際に画面表示をしているインスタンス」＝TopView(実際に画面表示をしているインスタンス)の認識でいました。